# Intro to probability at least question

Tags: probability, statistics

I am horrible with probability since I was a pure math major, what do I do here I know its 1 - the complement but the problem is I am choosing from $4$, do I use the binomial coefficient?

Let there be $12$ marbles, $7$ green, $2$ brown, $3$ blue. Find the chances that at least 2 are of the same color if you only select 4. My thinking is: I am choosing 4 out of 12 however I need to consider complement of $\geq 2$ which is being identically $1$.

Comment: I agree that the best approach is to find the probability of the complement. Was that your only question?

Comment: well I get that part but is it then $1- P(1)$ though? because I get confused where instead of the prob being from the total space, ($12$) its only from 4.

Comment: Try applying the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by $P(1)$. The complement of "at least 2 colors are the same" is "all the colors are different".

Comment: If there are 3 possible colors and you select 4, at least 2 are of the same color (always)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(\text{at least two of the four marbles are of the same color})\\=1-P(\text{at most one of the four marbles is of the same colour})\\=1-P(\text{the four marbles are all of different colours})\\=1,$$ by the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), since there are only three colours to choose from.